# C# XML Serialization having elements side-by-side

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I am currently trying to understand the concept of serializing objects to XML with C#. I already got to a point where everything is working fine, but now I got the task to format the XML Output file in such a way, where the elements are side-by-side instead of underneath each other. For example:

**This is how it needs to look like**

```
<House>
  <Address>
    <Street>Some Street</Street><HouseNo>123</HouseNo><State>Texas</State>
  </Address>
<House>
```

**But I only manage to get it to look like this:**

```
<House>
  <Address>
    <Street>Some Street</Street>
    <HouseNo>123</HouseNo>
    <State>Texas</State>
  </Address>
</House>
```

Is there any way to format the output the way I described in the first example? Any help would be much appreciated.

I already tried to change some `XmlWriterSettings`, like `Indent` or `NewLineHandling` but none have worked so far. I also tried to read the XmlSerializer Code to try and understand what is happening or where to make changes to get to the result I want but that didn't seem to go all well.

Comment: The XML is valid and serialized regardless of any whitespace (tabs, new lines, line feeds, spaces) that are present around the elements. The way you want to format the XML, presumably for human readability is non-standard. Do just want all elements in `Address` on one line or, is it all leaf children?

Comment: _"I got the task to format the XML Output file in such a way"_ - somebody seems to be on your back. Better watch your 6. This is a ridiculous requirement. The one-liner is even less readable (to me at least). I'd try to discuss it away. **It's not at all worth the time and effort (_and developer salary_) put into it**.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need all elements in Address to be in one line. I honestly don't really know why I have to format it that way, because as you already mentioned, it is not standard for human readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could crate an address class with custom serialization, here is a [full working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FB3qUk),

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var houseBefore = new House
        {
            Address = new FlatAddress
                              {
                                 Street = "SomeStreet",
                                 HouseNo = "123",
                                 State = "Texas"
                              }
        };
        
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(House));
        string xml;
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, houseBefore);
            xml = writer.ToString();
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(xml);
        
        House houseAfter;
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            houseAfter = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as House;
        }
        
        Debug.Assert(houseBefore.Address.Street == houseAfter.Address.Street);
        Debug.Assert(houseBefore.Address.HouseNo == houseAfter.Address.HouseNo);
        Debug.Assert(houseBefore.Address.State == houseAfter.Address.State);
    }
}

public sealed class House
{
    public FlatAddress Address { get; set; }
}

public sealed class FlatAddress : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string Street { set; get; }
    public string HouseNo { set; get; }
    public string State { set; get; }
    
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return default;
    }
    
    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                switch (reader.Name)
                {
                    case nameof(Street):
                        this.Street = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        break;

                    case nameof(HouseNo):
                        this.HouseNo = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        break;

                    case nameof(State):
                        this.State = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString(nameof(Street), this.Street);
        var houseNoXml = new XElement(nameof(HouseNo), this.HouseNo);
        writer.WriteRaw(houseNoXml.ToString());
        var stateXml = new XElement(nameof(State), this.State);
        writer.WriteRaw(stateXml.ToString());
        
        if (writer.Settings.NewLineHandling == NewLineHandling.Replace)
        {
            writer.WriteRaw(writer.Settings.NewLineChars);
        }
        
        if (writer.Settings.Indent)
        {
            writer.WriteRaw(writer.Settings.IndentChars);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I was thinking about XSLT ... but this is better, I think. (**If** you so desperately need to do it in the first place)

Comment: @Fildor, I guess it depends if you want `Address`es to always do this or you just need it for a one off document. I can confirm, its unlikely to be worth the effort.